# Can you give some information for rothe method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, book-recommendation

I want to learn a numerical method for PDEs other than finite difference method. After some research on internet i have found Rothe method and it looks interesting to me. Unfortunately, i couldn't find a good book/ notes for starting. Can you suggest me a book to study? What is prerequisites/corequisites for the Rothe method?

Thanks in advance...